# Get more than 200 results on vk vides.search api

Tags: python, vk

I just started using vk api in python and I am looking for a way to get more than 200 videos (possibly by using multiple api calls) for a specific query.

To be more specific, each api call to video.search returns the number of videos that the search yields (the same number can be seen when searching from the website). Is there a way to get let's say the next videos in that list?

thanks!
:-)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [execute](https://vk.com/dev/execute) method.

The limit of videos is 1000, so it's better to have 5 requests with requesting 200 videos

For example, the value of attribute "code" can be:

```
var i = 0;
var response = API.video.search({"count":200, "q":"Nirvana", "hd":0});
var count = response["count"];
var items = response["items"];
while (i != 4){
i =i + 1;
response = API.video.search({"count": 200,"q":"Nirvana", "hd":0, "offset":i*200});
items.push(response["items"]);
count = count + response["count"];
}
return {"items":items,"count": count};
```

Comment: see my answer. There are two inaccuracies in your answer: 1. One can find more than 1K videos using the video.search API. 2. Using offset the way you did will not necessary yield 1000 videos as from the second call and on there are repetitions so with your code you may a. skip videos and b. get less than 1000 unique videos

Comment: @hashark, I only offered the way he should go, but not the ready method

Comment: of course. no complaints. I just corrected minor details. Thanks for your response :-)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use the 'offset' parameter. I was not aware of it when I asked the question...
I was able to get max of about 4K videos but it take more than 20 API calls as some of the results are repeated i.e., if on the first call I got 200 videos on the second API call with offset 200 I am getting a list of 200 videos but some of them already appeared in the previous list.
In addition, you don't always get 200 videos. Sometimes you will get less (and still repetitions are possible).